# Airflow - Unable to use jinja template for resources in Kubernetes Pod Operator task

Tags: jinja2, airflow, kubernetespodoperator

Airflow - Unable to use jinja template for resources in Kubernetes Pod Operator task.
Able to use jinja template for environment variables, image but not able to use for resources to specify CPU and memory (request and limit).

Answer (score 1):

For [`apache-airflow-providers-cncf-kubernetes>=5.0.0`](https://pypi.org/project/apache-airflow-providers-cncf-kubernetes/#description):

There is support for templating [`container_resources`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/85f0ef35b831db61a4a6ac83f370cfff5323b842/airflow/providers/cncf/kubernetes/operators/pod.py#L268):

```
from kubernetes.client import models as k8s
from airflow.providers.cncf.kubernetes.operators.pod import KubernetesPodOperator

KubernetesPodOperator(
    ...,
    container_resources=k8s.V1ResourceRequirements(
        requests={"memory": "{{ params.value }}", "cpu": "{{ params.value1 }}"},
        limits={"memory": "{{ params.value }}", "cpu": "{{ params.value1 }}"},
    )
)
```

For older versions that uses `resources` as dict:

This happens because `resources` is not a templated field (see [source code](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/fb478c00cdc5e78d5e85fe5ac103707c829be2fb/airflow/providers/cncf/kubernetes/operators/kubernetes_pod.py#L168-L177)). You can still get the functionality you desire by creating a custom operator as:

```
from airflow.providers.cncf.kubernetes.operators.kubernetes_pod import KubernetesPodOperator
class MyKubernetesPodOperator(KubernetesPodOperator):
    template_fields = KubernetesPodOperator.template_fields + ('resources',)
```

Now in `MyKubernetesPodOperator` the `resources` parameter is templated and you can use Jinja syntax with it.

Comment: But I think as of airflow version 2.1.4 developments, I can't use dict for `resources` parameter as it initialises the operator with constructor value as str (not evaluated as template strings happen at DAG's runtime) -> Error received is as `airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Expected <class 'kubernetes.client.models.v1_resource_requirements.V1ResourceRequirements'>, got <class 'str'>`

Comment: in newer cncf provider resources accept V1ResourceRequirements not dict.
This answer was written several months ago..

Comment: Yes, inheriting and overloading the `KubernetesPodOperator` constructor is what I don't want to do as it adds lots of maintenance to the code when Airflow plans/changes the KubernetesPodOperator implementation.

Comment: Thanks @Elad. Yeah, I understood it. But the best practice to use Airflow is to have minimum maintenance code.

Comment: can someone provide a more detailed example please?

Comment: @EladKalif thanks, much clearer to me! will this resources flag be useful if I am using the pod_template_file arg instead? I am specifying my resource requirements there.`kubernetes_task =KubernetesPodOperator(pod_template_file=POD_TEMPLATE_FILE)`